# Android Listview displays the item only when focussed

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

I am trying to display a listview from a string array, when a button event occurs.This is how i do it

btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
      public void onClick(View v) {
        list_view.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (MyActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, String_array));

                  }
        });
```

Now, on button click, it displays a blank list view.if I focus on the list view, then the items load, disappears when not focused. Any idea of where I am going wrong?

My layout set up for button and list view :

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="101dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Search" />

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     </ListView>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I got the same behavior for an AutocompleteTextView as well. I added this line setTheme(android.R.style.Theme); before setcontentview and it then worked...

Comment: Could You provide more details? The issue might be in Your layout setup.

Comment: Hey Thanks. I have included my set up code in the question

Comment: check out http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf and http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html. I guess the issue might be in layout_height for list view. Also, have You tried set cachecolorhint and selector to list?

Comment: thanks!!...it worked...after changing  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 to android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line...

Comment: though, my list went black when i scrolled.However fixed it by setting list_view.setCacheColorHint(0);